# Is there a way to separate the two meanings of the "inline" keyword (ODR relaxation vs. function code inlining)

Tags: c++

I think I fully understand the meaning of the `inline` keyword in C++.  Specifically it means two only semi-related things:

1. The ODR rule is relaxed for the function declared `inline`.  Thus you can have the same function symbol defined in multiple TUs without getting an error when linking them.  This allows a function to be defined in a header.
2. It is a *suggestion* to the compiler that it should replace invocations of the functions with a copy of the function's compiled code, rather than a `call` instruction to the address of the function symbol.

I can understand that these two meanings are necessarily related in one direction:  2 must imply 1.  #2 requires that the function definition be available to all TUs that invoke the function.  Therefore the function definition must exist in multiple TUs.  Therefore the ODR needs to be relaxed to avoid linker errors.

But my question is about the other direction - why is the language designed such that 1 must imply 2?

It seems reasonable, in some cases and for some design decisions, to want to be able to relax the ODR for a function, *without* suggesting to the compiler that it should actually inline the function code.  If I have a function I want to distribute via a header file I must mark it as `inline` to relax the ODR (#1).  But now I am forced into #2 even if I have specific knowledge that in terms of performance, the function is not a good candidate for inlining.

My understanding is that this unwanted implication does not exist for template functions.  The ODR is automatically relaxed for template functions (as it must be).  That allows me to use `inline` only as a performance suggestion.

I understand that distributing functions in header files, as opposed to e.g. a static library, can be a bad idea.  But as a programmer, there is some possibility that I know what I am doing, and I would like that flexibility.  I have that flexibility with template functions so why not non-template functions?

Or is there a portable way to relax the ODR without suggesting that the function be inlined?  E.g. on MSVC you can do this:

```
__declspec(noinline) inline void Foo() {}
```

Here `inline` relaxes the ODR, but `__declspec(noinline)` requests that the compiler *not* actually inline the call.  But `__declspec(noinline)` isn't portable.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure modern (decent) compilers don't care at all about the "suggestion" to actually inline code. But anyway, I don't think there is any portable way to do what you want; maybe a macro that does `__declspec(noinline)` for the compilers you care about (like `__attribute__(( noinline ))` for GCC) would satisfy you?

Comment: I was under the impression that most modern compilers don't use the `inline` keyword as an input to their decisions on whether to generate inline assembly at all. If that's right, maybe `inline` as an optimizer suggestion was part of the original intent, but now the keyword means only the ODR-related details, and only compiler-specific flags and extensions control code inlining.

Comment: @aschepler it appears that modern compilers do use it as a heuristic: https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/inline-hints/

Comment: I have had compilers that actually inline the code during Debug mode; that is the compiler listens and uses your suggestion for inline in Debug mode.  In Release mode, the compiler may ignore your suggestion for inlining.

Comment: Why are you including this "don't inline" function in a header, rather than distributing it an a library file?

Comment: *If* it the compiler takes the hint only when the `inline` keyword is present and not when the function is inline in general, then you could use a static member function and define the function within the class definition. Then the function will be implicitly inline, without the use of the keyword.

Comment: I may have missed what you’re trying to get at, but it sounds like you may find the `static` keyword useful.

Comment: @Nelfeal - thanks, yeah on MSVC I've not found a case where the `inline` keyword affected the compiler's decision on inline expansion.  On Debug builds, nothing is inlined no matter what (even with `__forceinline`).  For Release builds, things are inlined pretty aggressively (unless the `__declspec(noinline)` is used).  But still, there might be a boundary case where the compiler uses `inline` as input to its decision.  Anyway I take your general point.  And thanks for `__attribute__(( noinline ))`, that allows me control for the compilers I care about.

Comment: @eerorika Thanks that seems pretty definitive.  So this is a potential issue after all.  I guess, if I really care about this stuff, the thing to do is 1.) Use `inline` when I need to relax the ODR 2.) If I don't want the compiler interpreing `inline` as a hint for inline expansion, use `__declspec(noinline)` or ` __attribute__(( noinline ))` to counteract the inline hint.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm - sometimes header files are a lot quicker and easier to use, build-wise, then linking to libraries.  Certainly providing a compiled binary is not practical if you want to support a lot of different compilation targets.  To cover arbitrary architectures, you have to provide the source one way or the other.  Look at the Boost "libraries", the majority are just headers.  Some (most? all?) of this is because they use templates but I guess in some cases it is to make using the functionality easier and avoid the need to have builds for all supported architectures.

Comment: @DavidStone:  What does your above comment have to do with my comment?  All I'm saying is that the compiler may not ignore the `inline` request in all cases.  Many people state that the compiler ignores the `inline` suggestion.

Comment: @eerorika - Regarding your suggestion about using a static member function - hmm that is not something I had thought of thanks.  But the question shifts from how compilers interpret the `inline` keyword, to how how compilers interpret member functions defined within the class definition.  The ODR rule is relaxed of course.  But is it also a hint for inline expansion, just like the `inline` keyword is for some compilers?  I don't know.  If not, then it is a good solution.  If so, I am back where I started.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews my apologies I was responding to another comment and copy-and-pasted your username accidentally.  I fixed my response.

Comment: Why do you care if the compiler inlines your code or not? The compiler usually has an objective when deciding to inline or not. Is it optimizing for speed or space. You can expresses these higher level objectives to the compiler then let it work out the best way to achieve this objective.

Comment: @DavidStone Then you could include the source in a .cpp file that your users add to their project.  If it's big enough you don't want to inline it, you shouldn't be compiling that function in every Translation Unit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But `__declspec(noinline)` isn't portable.

You can make it portable to all implementations that have an analogous attribute by using a platform detection macro. GCC and Clang have `__attribute__((noinline))`.

---

Another approach is to simply not care. The compiler still has the option to ignore the preference that it perceives to have been implied. If the inline expansion would be expensive (because the function is big), a smart compiler should refrain from expanding it.

Comment: OK, so my assumption that the *language* specified that the `inline` keyword is a suggestion for inline expansion was wrong.  It is a little confusing that, per the language, the `inline` keyword is unrelated to *inline* expansion!  I guess my complaint then drops to the compiler implementors then - they (according to reports) take `inline` as a suggestion/heueristic for inline expansion.  I just want to say something about the ODR and they interpret something additional.  But if GCC and Clang have their own non-portable syntax as you provide, at least I have a work-around

Comment: @DavidStone the language says very very little about optimisation in general.

Comment: @DavidStone The language doesn't even require or assume that there is any such thing as compiled instructions - so an implementation that simply interpreted function definitions as needed directly from the source would be valid, though inefficient. The only related requirement is that functions somehow do what their statements say, as far as you can tell from input, output, and other "observable effects".

Comment: The language **does** say "The inline specifier indicates to the implementation that inline substitution of the function body at the point of call is to be preferred to the usual function call mechanism." ([dcl.inline]/2).

Comment: @DavisHerring Hmm, you're right.